# Twitter API - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, twitter

Hey guys I am trying to get some tweets by using the twitter API but I get this error when I run it:

> Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\final_app\search_tweets.php on line 26 (commented on the code which line it is.

Here is my code, can anyone give any suggestion?

```
<?php include "library/twitteroauth.php"; ?>
<?php
 $consumer = "xx";
 $consumersecret = "xx";
 $accesstoken = "xx";
 $accesstokensecret = "";

 $twitter = new TwitterOAuth($consumer, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Team 11 - Final App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action ="" method="POST">
        <label> Search : <input type="text" name="keyword"/></label>
    </form>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['keyword'])){
            $tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q='.$_POST['keyword'].'&since_id=24012619984051000&max_id=250126199840518145&result_type=recent&count=50');

            foreach($tweets as $tweet){
                foreach($tweet as $t){
                    echo $t->text;   //THIS IS LINE 26
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: After `$tweets = $twitter->get(...)` put `print_r($tweets)` and see/show what is inside.

Comment: @barell This is what I get:

stdClass Object ( [statuses] => Array ( ) [search_metadata] => stdClass Object ( [completed_in] => 0.009 [max_id] => 2.5012619984052E+17 [max_id_str] => 250126199840518145 [query] => honda [refresh_url] => ?since_id=250126199840518145&q=honda&result_type=recent&include_entities=1 [count] => 50 [since_id] => 2.4012619984051E+16 [since_id_str] => 24012619984051000 ) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case your response from Twitter API hasn't got any feeds. Other problem is that your `foreach` loop is not compatible with Twitter API v1.1 because the response is:

```
{
    "statuses": [
        // list of feeds
    ],
    "search_metadata": [
        // extra info about your query
    ]
}
```

So your loop should looks like this:

```
$tweets = $twitter->get(/* your url */);
if(isset($tweets->statuses) && is_array($tweets->statuses)) {
    if(count($tweets->statuses)) {
        foreach($tweets->statuses as $tweet) {
            echo $tweet->text;
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'The result is empty';
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I don't get anything in return. No error, but its a blank page.

Comment: Because there is no tweets in resultset.

Comment: Oh, I removed the since_id and max_id and now I get results. :) Thanks!